# Open Ball under the p-adic Norm

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I'm trying to figure how, if it's even possible, to draw an open ball using the p-adic norm.  My definition of the p-adic norm I'm using is:

$ \lvert x \rvert_p $ = $p^{-ord_px}$ if $x \neq 0$ and zero otherwise.

Any specific examples would be greatly appreciated, or even a link to a website / document which outlines how one would go about drawing such a ball.

I've had a think about this for a while, and have got nowhere.  The main reason for asking is that this will hopefully go into an (undergrad) essay I'm writing.

Thanks :)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space, about the ball $B(x;r)$.

Comment: Observe that this metric renders weird results, from a point of view of the usual real metric: every triangle is isosceles and any two non-disjoint balls are contained *in each other* (!). Also, any point inside a ball is its center (!!)

Comment: There are many cases when the Julia set of a polynomial acting on $\mathbb C$ is totally disconnected and looks exactly like $\mathbb Z_p$, which is the closed ball in $\mathbb Q_p$ of radius $1$, centered at $0$ (and the open ball of radius $1+\varepsilon$ for small enough $\varepsilon$).